# R - Find the location of the file

Tags: r

Below is the wrapper function I created to find the file location. The function works, but I would like to know if there is any simpler solution than this.

The purpose of this function is to find the folder of the file. Since `list.files` returns the directory and the file name, I cant use this as an input for `setwd()`.

`setwd(list.files(fileName))` will not work

**Questions:**

1. Is there any function which will give the folder so I dont have to create a wrapper function?
2. How can I find the last "/" in a string. I played with `regexpr("\\\[^\\.]*$", Dir)` and kept getting error.

Any answers or feedbacks are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
findFileLocation <- function(FileName,...) {
  #Find the location of the file
  Dir <- list.files(pattern = FileName, recursive = TRUE)
  #> Dir
  #[1] "10-30/No time line/folderNames.csv"

  positionOfDot <- regexpr("\\.[^\\.]*$", Dir)
  #> positionOfDot
  #[1] 18

  numCharFile <- nchar(FileName)
  #> numCharFile
  #[1] 15

  numCharDir <- nchar(Dir)
  #> numCharDir
  #[1] 21

  fileDir <-  substr(Dir, 1, (numCharDir-(numCharFile+1))) #+1 is to account for the "/"
  fileDir #returns the actual location of the file
}

test <- findFileLocation("folderNames.csv")
```

from here I can execute the code:

```
setwd(file.path(mainDir, test))
```

Note: basename and dirname are already tried.

Comment: `?basename` might be useful

Comment: Or `dirname()`. Hard to tell since we can't run and test the code. What is the desired result here? You want the complete relative folder path?

Comment: Results of `dirname()` is ` "."` and `basename()` is `[1] "folderNames.csv"`. 

`list.files()` is giving me  "#[1] "10-30/No time line/folderNames.csv"" but I cant use that in `setwd()'. I want the sub folder names.

Comment: When I run `dirname("10-30/No time line/folderNames.csv")` I get `"10-30/No time line"`, but you claim you get `""`? That seems odd. Are you certain `Dir` contains the folder names?

Comment: oooh now it makes sense. I tried `dirname(Dir)` or `dirname(list.files(pattern = FileName, recursive = TRUE))` and it worked. Thanks @MrFlick

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MrFlick. The answer is `dirname(list.files(pattern = FileName, recursive = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

Since the first question was already answered, let me answer the second question here:

> How can I find the last "/" in a string. I played with `regexpr("\\\[^\\.]*$", Dir)` and kept getting error.

The error message I get when I try to use this regular expression is:

> Error: '[' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\["

The problem reported here is that a third backslash is used (`\`) where in fact a forward slash (`/`) was intended. Using `regexpr("\\/[^\\.]*$", Dir)` instead doesn't throw any errors. However, it doesn't do what was intended, i.e. it does not find the last forward slash. This is because this regular expression searches for forward slashes that are not followed by any *dots* (`.`), where in fact the idea was to search for forward slashes that are not followed by any (more) *forward slashes*.

Thus, the correct regular expression for the described use case is `regexpr("\\/[^\\/]*$", Dir)`.

```
Dir <- "10-30/No time line/folderNames.csv"
regexpr("\\/[^\\/]*$", Dir)
# returns 19
```